# Navigate in uiviewcontroller iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, uiviewcontroller, navigation

[image]

I have a problem in memory management, when navigate to specific `UIViewController`

Example:

I have 3 `UIViewController` and use Storyboard modal segue and I stay in the first and I need go to the number 3 directly

I use this code works fine, but when i need return to the 1 and I if repeat this code. I receive a memory warning and crash later.

This is my code:

go to view 3 ->

```
UIStoryboard *storybord = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UIViewController * viewTree = [storybord instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Three"];
[self presentViewController:viewTree animated:YES completion:nil];
```

go to view 1 ->

```
UIStoryboard *storybord = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UIViewController * viewOne = [storybord instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"One"];
[self presentViewController:viewOne animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: To go back, dismiss the controller you presented. From controller 1 or 3 call `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]`. You seem to be presenting a new version of 1 over 3 from what you posted rather than dismissing 3 which will take you back to 1.

Comment: What does the memory warning and crash say?

Comment: @RoryMcKinnel i use [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil] but dont work =(

Comment: @StephenFox When go to view 1 to 3 and return. several times and finally have a receive a memory warning and crash the app

Comment: I imagine the memory warning is because you are constantly presenting a new controller and never dismissing any. `dismissViewControllerAnimated` when executed in "your back to 1" handler should be working. Would need to see more code now for your controller 1 and controller 3 button press handlers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be constantly be presenting each view controller over each other, which is raising the memory warning issue. To present `ViewControllerThree` use the following code in `ViewControllerOne`

```
@implementation ViewControllerOne

- (IBAction) goto3 {

      UIStoryboard *storybord = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
      UIViewController * viewTree = [storybord instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Three"];
      // Brings you to the third view controller.
      [self presentViewController:viewTree animated:YES completion:nil];
}

@end
```

And then to go back to `ViewControllerOne` implement this code in `ViewControllerThree`

```
@implementation ViewControllerThree

-(IBAction) backTo1 {
    // Dismisses the third view and brings you back to the first view controller.
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```